# Funcion calculadora

Tags: javascript

Como bien dice el titulo, tengo un problema a la hora de que viaje las variables con el valor de los numeros, he empezado ahora mismo con funciones asi que a lo mejor no le estoy pasando bien los parametros, pero cuando me salta el alert en la function suma me dice isNan o sea se pasa como string entiendo. (Estoy intentando hacer una Calculadora Arcaica)

> ```
>   var operacion = prompt("Que deseas hacer? Sumar/Restar/Multipicar/Dividir").toLocaleLowerCase();
> ```

```
    function operadores(operador1, operador2){
        
        var numero1 = parseInt(prompt("Dime el primer numero que deseas introducir"));
        
        var numero2 = parseInt(prompt("Dime el segundo numero que deseas introducir"));
        
    }



    function sumar(num1, num2){
            
        alert("El total de la suma es " + (num1 + num2));

    }

    if(operacion == "sumar"){
        
        operadores(operador1, operador2);

        
        sumar(operador1, operador2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que no le estas pasando los valores que obtienes del prompt por referencia al momento de llamar a la función operadores(), entonces los estas dejando sin asignar, lo que te podría funcionar es hacer dos variables globales con un var fuera de las funciones, así cuando preguntes por el prompt, independientemente de el tipo de operación, puedes acceder desde cualquier "función de operación" a las dos valores globales.

Comment: Buenas, lo primero gracias por responder y lo segundo te refieres a las variables del prompt que las genere fuera de la funcion operadores, y dentro de la funcion les paso el valor prompt?

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar! Mil gracias.

Comment: Los promps para obtener los valores las variables numero 1 y numero 2 lo puedes hacer afuera o en la misma funcion, lo importante seria que hicieras que esas dos variables fueran globales para que otras funciones puedan acceder a sus valores. No hay de que.